# add last value from list in column A into list in column b

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```py
    df_test = pd.DataFrame({"f":['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                            "d":['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y'],
                            "low": [0,5,2,4,5,10,4,8],
                            "up": [5,10,4,6,10,15,8,12],
                            "z": [1,3,6,2,3,7,5,10]})
```

and what I first have to do is to convert the columns 'low', 'up' and 'z' to list for each (grouped by) 'f' and 'd'. so this is what I did:

```py
    dff = df_test.groupby(['f','d'])[['low', 'up', 'z']].agg(list).reset_index()
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

Now I want to extract the last value from the lists in column 'up' and add it to the lists in column 'low'.
But this is unfortunately not working:

```py
    dff['last'] = (dff['up'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])).tolist()
    dff['new'] = dff['low'].append(dff['last'])
```

I get an error message "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis".
The column 'new' should have these values:
[0,5,10], [2,4,6], [5,10,15], [4,8,12]

any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
dff['new'] = dff['low'] + pd.Series([[x[1]] for x in dff['up']])
```

Output:

```
   f  d      low        up        z          new
0  a  x   [0, 5]   [5, 10]   [1, 3]   [0, 5, 10]
1  a  y   [2, 4]    [4, 6]   [6, 2]    [2, 4, 6]
2  b  x  [5, 10]  [10, 15]   [3, 7]  [5, 10, 15]
3  b  y   [4, 8]   [8, 12]  [5, 10]   [4, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
dff["new"] = dff.apply(lambda x: [*x["low"], x["up"].pop()], axis=1)
print(dff)
```

Prints:

```
   f  d      low    up        z          new
0  a  x   [0, 5]   [5]   [1, 3]   [0, 5, 10]
1  a  y   [2, 4]   [4]   [6, 2]    [2, 4, 6]
2  b  x  [5, 10]  [10]   [3, 7]  [5, 10, 15]
3  b  y   [4, 8]   [8]  [5, 10]   [4, 8, 12]
```

---

If you want to keep the last element in `up` column:

```py
dff["new"] = dff.apply(lambda x: [*x["low"], x["up"][-1]], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the mutability of lists, use a pure python loop that should be more efficient than `apply`.

To copy the element:

```
for l, u in zip(dff['low'], dff['up']):
    l.append(u[-1])
```

Output:

```
   f  d          low        up        z
0  a  x   [0, 5, 10]   [5, 10]   [1, 3]
1  a  y    [2, 4, 6]    [4, 6]   [6, 2]
2  b  x  [5, 10, 15]  [10, 15]   [3, 7]
3  b  y   [4, 8, 12]   [8, 12]  [5, 10]
```

To move the element:

```
for l, u in zip(dff['low'], dff['up']):
    l.append(u.pop(-1))
```

Output:

```
   f  d          low    up        z
0  a  x   [0, 5, 10]   [5]   [1, 3]
1  a  y    [2, 4, 6]   [4]   [6, 2]
2  b  x  [5, 10, 15]  [10]   [3, 7]
3  b  y   [4, 8, 12]   [8]  [5, 10]
```

For a new column use slicing:

```
dff['new'] = dff['low'] + dff['up'].str[-1:]
```

Or a list comprehension (should be slower):

```
dff['new'] = [l+[u[-1]] for l, u in zip(dff['low'], dff['up'])]
```

Output:

```
   f  d      low        up        z          new
0  a  x   [0, 5]   [5, 10]   [1, 3]   [0, 5, 10]
1  a  y   [2, 4]    [4, 6]   [6, 2]    [2, 4, 6]
2  b  x  [5, 10]  [10, 15]   [3, 7]  [5, 10, 15]
3  b  y   [4, 8]   [8, 12]  [5, 10]   [4, 8, 12]
```